# CreateProcessA() Run As Administrator with the cmd output in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, process, createprocess

I have created a function in a dll to call a exe in the Command line using the CreateProcessA. It will be called from some other external Exe which runs under Administrator user. But the process exits before printing anything. I have checked the path. I got the error "The pipeline closed".

```
int execute(const char* cmd, std::string &output)
{

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
    {
        appendLineToFile(LOGFILENAME, "StdoutRd CreatePipe");
        return 1;
    }

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
    {
        appendLineToFile(LOGFILENAME, "Stdout SetHandleInformation");
        return 1;
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFOA siStartInfo;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    bSuccess = CreateProcessA(NULL,
        (char*)cmd,     // command line 
        NULL,          // process security attributes 
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
        0,             // creation flags 
        NULL,          // use parent's environment 
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);

    if (!bSuccess)
    {
        appendLineToFile(LOGFILENAME, "Createprocess failed");
        //printf("createprocess failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
        // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
        // of the child process, for example. 

        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);

        // Close handles to the stdin and stdout pipes no longer needed by the child process.
        // If they are not explicitly closed, there is no way to recognize that the child process has ended.

        CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);

        DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
        CHAR chBuf[1024];
        BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

        bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, 1024, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0)
        {
            appendLineToFile(LOGFILENAME, "Cannot read from AgentInstaller.exe");
            return 1;
        }
        chBuf[dwRead] = '\0';
        output = chBuf;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing the manifest file in the properties privilages too.

Any help or suggestions will be helpful

sample method call

```
std::string installcommand = "C:\\Program Files(x86)\\xxxx\\xxxx\\Installer.exe install"
std::string output;
execute(installcommand.c_str(),output);
```

Three cases need to be satisfied

- The process should run under Admin privilage
- The process should return the output
- The process should get access from the parent process it is called. Means no username or password/ token should be used.

Answer (score 0):

A child process inherits the parent token, per [How User Account Control Works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works): "*Child processes inherit the user access token from the parent process. Both the parent and child processes, however, must have the same integrity level.*". So, in the usual case of default [integrity levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/mandatory-integrity-control), the child process will run elevated when started from an elevated process.

One problem with the posted code, however, is that the parent process attempts to read the child pipe in one shot with just one `ReadFile` call. Instead, the pipe should be read in a loop until `ReadFile` fails with `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` to indicate that the child process ended (or otherwise closed the pipe).

That amounts to this section of the code:

```
        DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
        CHAR chBuf[1024];
        BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

        bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, 1024, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0)
        {
            appendLineToFile(LOGFILENAME, "Cannot read from AgentInstaller.exe");
            return 1;
        }
        chBuf[dwRead] = '\0';
        output = chBuf;
```

being replaced with:

```
        for (;;)
        {
            CHAR chBuf[4096]; DWORD dwRead;

            if (!ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, sizeof(chBuf), &dwRead, NULL))
            {
                switch (GetLastError())
                {
                    case ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE: return 0;  // end-of-pipe, done

                    case ERROR_MORE_DATA:   continue;  // n/a here

                //  case ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE:
                //  case ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED:
                    default:                return 1;  // error, check GetLastError
                }
            }
            if (dwRead == 0)                return 0;  // end-of-file, done

            output.append(chBuf, dwRead);
        }
```

The following sample code requires elevation to write to the `C:\Windows` directory:

```
std::string installcommand = "cmd /c echo Hello Pipe! >C:\\Windows\\testing.tmp & type C:\\Windows\\testing.tmp";
std::string output;
execute(installcommand.c_str(), output);
std::cout << output << std::endl;
```

- when run at a regular non-elevated prompt:

  ```
  C:\etc>sample

  Access is denied.
  The system cannot find the file specified.
  ```
- when run at an elevated prompt:

  ```
  C:\etc>sample

  Hello Pipe!
  ```

Comment: Still I am getting 109 ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE error in the process with the above code

Comment: @pewex That's not an error (usually), it's how you know the child process closed its end of the pipe (usually because it completed). From [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile#pipes): "*If an anonymous pipe is being used and the write handle has been closed, when ReadFile attempts to read using the pipe's corresponding read handle, the function returns FALSE and GetLastError returns ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE*".